# Autocorrect resolved query in api.ai

Tags: ionic-framework, dialogflow-es

How to auto correct a question that is asked by the user and display it in api.ai
(for e.g) if we say "sithik, tell me something" it identifies as "cd ,tell me something". I need to display the question asked in my app. instead of displaying the resolved query as "cd ,tell me something", instead i want to display " sithik, tell me something"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. Google simply transcribes the audio. The best it could do is giving you back the ranking number for the transcribed word, like 80% probability xxx, 15% yyy, 5% zzz. There is no such thing as verbatim transcription of the original utterance.